# Identities between let/lambda/defun expressions and simplifying nested progn

Tags: let-binding, defun

I learned that a `lambda` and `let` works as if they already include a `progn` in their definition. That is `(let ((x 1) (y 2) (z 3)) A B C)` works as if it had a `progn` after binding the variables: `(let ((x 1) (y 2) (z 3)) (<progn> A B C))`. `lambda` seems to have an "inherent" `progn` as well, such that `(funcall (lambda (x y z) A B C) 1 2 3)` is equivalent to `(let ((x 1) (y 2) (z 3)) A B C)`.

My question is:
a) What are the identifies between `lambda`, `let` and `progn`? (i.e. how would you implement `lambda` and `progn` just using `let`?);
b) Is `(progn (progn (A) (B) (C)))` always equivalent to `(progn ((A) (B) (C)))`?

Comment: Too many questions, and not very clear. Have you tried the Elisp manual first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `lambda` seems to have an "inherent" `progn` as well, such that `(funcall (lambda (x y z) A B C) 1 2 3)` is equivalent to `(let ((x 1) (y 2) (z 3)) A B C)`.

"Equivalent" is a strong word. Calling a `lambda` with a set of arguments may have a similar effect to evaluating the `lambda`'s body with the appropriate `let` bindings in place, but their corresponding semantics are quite different.

> a) What are the identifies between `lambda`, `let` and `progn`?

Are you asking how they relate/compare to one another?

- [`progn`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequencing.html) is pure sequential evaluation of Lisp forms
- [`let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html) is the same but with local variable binding at the start and unbinding at the end
- [`lambda`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html) evaluates to an anonymous function under dynamic binding, and
  a closure under
  [`lexical-binding`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html)

> how would you implement `lambda` and `progn` just using `let`?

That depends on what you mean by "implement using `let`". You can't use `let` alone to define a function, macro, or special form that will do the same thing as either `lambda` or `progn`, but some rewriting is possible in the case of `progn`:

```el
;; Expressions of this form:
(progn BODY...)
;; can generally be written as:
(let () BODY...)
```

No such rewrite is possible for anonymous functions and closures in general, because their evaluation semantics and byte-compilation are quite different to those of `let`.

```el
;; For example, this expression:
(lambda (x) (1+ x))
;; is not, under dynamic binding, the same as:
(list 'lambda '(x) '(1+ x))
;; and not, under lexical binding, the same as:
(list 'closure '(t) '(x) '(+ x y))
```

> b) Is `(progn (progn (A) (B) (C)))` always equivalent to `(progn ((A) (B) (C)))`?

No, those two forms are never equivalent.

`(progn (progn (A) (B) (C)))` is valid Elisp which evaluates `(A)`, `(B)`, and `(C)` in that order, and returns the result of evaluating `(C)`.

`(progn ((A) (B) (C)))` is valid if and only if `(A)` is a valid `(lambda ...)` expression, as the first element of an evaluated list must already be (not evaluate to) a valid function object. In that case, `(B)` and `(C)` are evaluated and passed as arguments to the anonymous function/closure `(A)`, whose result is then returned by `progn`.

(I have the faint impression that expressions of the form `((lambda ...))` are meant to eventually be outlawed in Elisp, but I'm not sure.)

**Update from Comments**

> In asking b), I meant to ask about the semantics and evaluation of the "implicit" `progn` in `let`/`lambda` and an explicit `progn` in their body, i.e. how does `(let () (progn BODY...))` work?

`(let () (progn BODY...))` is effectively the same as `(progn (progn BODY...))`, which is effectively the same as `(progn BODY...)`, i.e. adding an explicit `progn` where there is already an implicit one is practically redundant/idempotent.

The special form `let` is actually implemented in terms of `progn`; see [`src/eval.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/eval.c#n922):

```c
DEFUN ("let", Flet, Slet, 1, UNEVALLED, 0,
       doc: /* Bind variables according to VARLIST then eval BODY.
The value of the last form in BODY is returned.
Each element of VARLIST is a symbol (which is bound to nil)
or a list (SYMBOL VALUEFORM) (which binds SYMBOL to the value of VALUEFORM).
All the VALUEFORMs are evalled before any symbols are bound.
usage: (let VARLIST BODY...)  */)
  (Lisp_Object args)
{
  /* Bind local variables according to first argument.  */
  Lisp_Object varlist = XCAR (args);
  ptrdiff_t count = SPECPDL_INDEX ();
  /* ...magic happens here...  */

  /* Pass remaining arguments to 'progn'.  */
  Lisp_Object elt = Fprogn (XCDR (args));

  /* Unbind local variables; return result of 'progn'.  */
  return SAFE_FREE_UNBIND_TO (count, elt);
}
```

Note that idiomatic Elisp avoids redundant nesting of `progn` where possible.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! In asking b), I meant to ask about the semantics and evaluation of the "implicit" `progn` in `let`/`lambda` and an explicit `progn` in their body, i.e. how does `(let () (progn BODY...))` work?

Comment: Very informative and helpful.

Comment: @hyiltiz Thanks, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: A good answer worths its weight in gold. Such good quality answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is `(funcall (lambda (arg1 arg2...) BODY...) val1 val2...)` equivalent to `(let ((arg1 val1) (arg2 val2)...) BODY...)`?

Comment: @Tobias The first part of my answer addresses that to an extent. Are you looking for any details in particular? The short answer is that, if two pieces of code are written differently, in terms of different special forms, then they are not equivalent, even if they largely exhibit similar effects. This principle underlies a lot of compiler optimisations and their potential risks.